# Sorting bootstrap table column by date

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

I've tried to amend my code to order my table records by date (when ordering by the date fields "Start date/Time" and "Finish Date/Time") but with no success. I used existing SO solutions to try and get the sorting to work but couldn't so if someone could help it would be much appreciated.

My table HTML and data is being provided by my ajax file.

HTML:

```
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title">Existing Log Entries</h3>
    </div>

    <form role="form">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="div-log-list"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
        </div>
    </form>

    <div style="margin:auto; width:99%;">
        <div id="entrieslist-div"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay" id="box-loading">
      <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $(function() {    
    // Populate log entry table
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajax/ajax-populate-log-entries.php", 
        success: function(result){
            $('#entrieslist-div').html(result);
            $('#box-loading').hide();
            $("#entrieslist").dataTable();
        }
    }); 
});
```

AJAX:

```
$counter = 0;

echo '<table id="entrieslist" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">';
echo '
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Start Date/Time</th>
            <th>Finish Date/Time</th>
            <th>Server Name</th>
            <th>Carried Out By</th>
            <th>Verified By</th>
            <th>Authorised By</th>
            <th>Work Carried Out</th>
            <th>Work Verification</th>
            <th>Change Reason</th>
            <th>Perceived Impact</th>
            <th>Rollback Process</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
';

echo '<tbody>';

foreach( $lines as $row) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '              
        <td>'.$row['start_date_time'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['finish_date_time'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['server_name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['carried_out_by'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['verified_by'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['authorised_by'].'</td> 
        <td>'.$row['work_carried_out'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['work_verified'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['change_reason'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['perceived_impact'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['rollback_process'].'</td>
';
echo '</tr>';}
$counter++;

echo '</tbody>';
echo '<tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Start Date/Time</th>
            <th>Finish Date/Time</th>
            <th>Server Name</th>
            <th>Carried Out By</th>
            <th>Verified By</th>
            <th>Authorised By</th>
            <th>Work Carried Out</th>
            <th>Work Verification</th>
            <th>Change Reason</th>
            <th>Perceived Impact</th>
            <th>Rollback Process</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>';           
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You can't sort records in php file then it can be visible in result

Comment: The problem is likely to be that the date is rendered as a string instead of a datetime. You can probably use a js plugin to resolve it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3vLLvscr/19/).

Answer (score 0):

As in your code I can see you are using `jQuery` you could use a plug in that will deliver you the exact functionality you are looking for and you don't have to reinvent the wheel. I use jQueries `dynatable` ([link](https://www.dynatable.com/)) plugin and didn't regret it by now!